# Fluent validation custom checking

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

using Fluent Validation C# library I have this code which current check the balance amount when user create new bank account.

```
public class BankAccountValidator : AbstractValidator<BankAccount>
{
    private AppDbContext db = new AppDbContext();

    public BankAccountValidator()
    {

        RuleFor(x => x.Balance).GreaterThanOrEqualTo(50).WithMessage($"A minimum of $100.00 balance is required to open Saving bank account type.");


    }

}
```

But, now I have added an enum for AccountType: SavingAccount and CurrentAccount. Rules is Saving account needs minimum $100.00 while current account needs minimum $300.00. How should I create a custom method for this checking using Fluent Validation library?

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `When` method:

```
When(x => x.AccountType == AccountType.SavingAccount, 
    () => RuleFor(x => x.Balance)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(100)
            .WithMessage($"A minimum of $100.00 balance is required to open Saving bank account type."));

When(x => x.AccountType == AccountType.CurrentAccount,
    () => RuleFor(x => x.Balance)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(300)
            .WithMessage($"A minimum of $300.00 balance is required to open Current bank account type."));
```